# String represents a road. One character travels on the road obeying the stops - Code challenge (advent.js day 5)

Tags: javascript, programming-challenge, strings

This is my code to solve [the 5th Adventjs challenge](https://adventjs.dev/en/challenges/2023/5). In that link you can read the instructions.

How can I improve it? It's a bit messy... and I'm repeating some part of the code.

- All must be in just one function

```
function cyberReindeer(road, time) {
  // Code here
  let theRoad = road;
  let roadNow = "";
  let greenLight = false;
  let roadArr = [];
  let stop = false;

  for (let i = 0; roadArr.length < time; i++) {
    if(greenLight !== true) {
      if (theRoad.charAt(i) !== "|" && stop !== true) {
        roadNow = theRoad.slice(0, i + 1)
          .replace("S", theRoad.charAt(i))
          .replace(/.$/,"S") 
          + theRoad.slice(i+1, theRoad.length);
        roadArr.push(roadNow);
      } else {
        while(roadArr.length < 5 && roadArr.length < time) {
          roadArr.push(roadNow);
          stop = true;
        }
        theRoad = theRoad.replace(/\|/g, '*');
        greenLight = true;
        roadNow = theRoad.slice(0, i + 1)
            .replace("S", ".")
            .replace(/.$/,"S") 
            + theRoad.slice(i+1, theRoad.length);
        if(roadArr.length < time) {
          roadArr.push(roadNow);
        }
      }
    } else {
      roadNow = theRoad.slice(0, i + 1)
            .replace("S", ".")
            .replace(/.$/,"S") 
            + theRoad.replace(/\|/g, '*')
            .slice(i+1, theRoad.length);
      roadArr.push(roadNow);
    }
  }
  return roadArr;
}
```

Comment: I have rolled back Rev 3 → 2. Please see [_What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## carefully read the requirements

The original problem asks us to

> Create a function that simulates the sled's movement ...

Somehow you leapt from that to

> All must be in just one function.

I see no prohibition on adding a helper function, if you find it convenient.

---

## painting a sprite

Santa is a
[spritely](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprite_(computer_graphics))
old elf.

Three times you use an odd idiom for erasing his sled and then re-drawing it.

It would be simpler to just copy the original `road` terrain
to the result each time (thereby "erasing" Sanata),
followed by placing Santa at his new location between a pair of
[substrings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring).

---

## velocity

Surprisingly, we're not modeling Santa's position with an `x` variable.
The current solution resembles computation by
[cellular automata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellular_automaton).

Having adopted that we might have a per time-step velocity `delta_x`,
so the update for each cycle is `x += delta_x`.
Setting that delta to zero would be a natural way to model Santa
stopping briefly for a Red light.

## consistent tests

I was a little surprised to see comparisons to `5` or to `time`
like this: `roadArr.length < time`.
It would have been more natural, at time-step `i`,
to compare against the loop variable: `i < time`.
Due to how the array grows, the effect is the same. Clarity could be improved.

## separation of concerns

This simulation of the world has two things to manage each time-step:

1. Stop lights ("barriers") sometimes switch from Red to Green
2. Santa moves, subject to Red light restrictions

It might be worth breaking out a pair of helper functions for that.

This simple world seems very physics based to me -- Santa performs
local sensing of an adjacent barrier.
Yet we have a global comparison to `5` which alters Santa's behavior.

I was hoping to see simpler logic where we change the world
by replacing all `|` bars with `*` stars when `i == 5`,
and then we let Santa move when there's no `|` bar.
The `stop` and `greenLight` booleans seem a bit much,
it's more things to juggle in your head than are necessary.

Comment: Thank you. I'll take all into consideration and give it another try.
When creating another function got this message: "Not allowed code outside the function. All your code MUST be inside cyberReindeer function"

Comment: Wow, picky execution environment. Ok, one function it is.

Comment: sharing [another solution](https://github.com/chardinsofia/adventjs2023/blob/main/day%205)
clearly got some insights and found very useful resources lately. thanks.